# what is the general way to find what dependencies do I need on .net core?

Tags: c#, dependencies, .net-core

I'm trying to create a simple .net core app from code I've found on some blogs. I'm on Ubuntu 16.04. My files are:

project.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.WebListener": "0.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.1"
        }
      },
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration; // for using IConfiguration
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel;
using System.IO; // for using Directory

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
  public class Program
  {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
          .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
          .AddJsonFile("hosting.json", optional: true)
          .Build();

      var host = new WebHostBuilder()
          .UseKestrel()
          .UseConfiguration(config)
          .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
          .UseIISIntegration()
          .UseStartup<Startup>()
          .Build();

      host.Run();
    }
  }
}
```

hosting.json

```
{
  "server.urls": "http://localhost:60000;http://localhost:60001"
}
```

The error I get when performing a *dotnet publish* is:

```
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Startup' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Also, remember please that I'm looking for a **general way** of knowing what dependencies do I miss.

Comment: This line `UseStartup<Startup>()` expecting Startup class. This is missing in your project.

Comment: @Sanket thank you, now it publishes successfully

Comment: refer this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29007962/how-can-i-diagnose-missing-dependencies-or-other-loader-failures-in-dnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking for dependencies, but you're not missing one. What you're missing is the `Startup` class, which either the blog you're following forgot to mention, or you didn't follow the directions.

The easiest way to create a new ASP.NET Core project is to run `dotnet new -t web`. The `Startup` class of that is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/rel/1.0.0/src/dotnet/commands/dotnet-new/CSharp_Web/Startup.cs).

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't going to be one. You may be able to find a tool like resharper that knows the official Microsoft packages and will tell you to "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" or whatever you are missing. However, it's to general of a problem to be reliably solved. In your example, you're missing a class that is supposed to be defined in your code. It could also be solved by including a package that had a Startup defined. Even supposing that were the case, how would it know the right one to choose? There could be a lot of packages that implement a Startup class. Foo.Startup, Bar.Startup, Microsoft.CrossPlatform.StartUp - all of these could conceivably implement Startup in such a way that you code compiled. How would a tool know which of those suited your needs? In general you will be finding a library to include and adding it, not writing code and then looking for an implementation of what you need.