# Different proejcts referencing different versions of a same package which version will be loaded at runtime

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget-package, .net-core

Let's say i've an **asp.net core/.net core** rest api project to run, it has **Folder A** in its project.json it references **Package C, version 1**, and **Folder B** whose project.json references **Package C, version 2**.

The build is fine. when do a '**dnu list**', **Folder A** says: **Package C, version 1**, and **Folder B** says: **Package C, version 2**.

So my question is **which version of Package C** will be loaded to memory **at runtime** (i don't think both will be loaded)?

Comment: Your terminology is strange. What is the relation of folders with project and package? Are you speaking of solution and projects within it? Also its not clear who or what references this packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here [NuGet Dependency Resolution](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/consume-packages/dependency-resolution) is the answer :)

Comment: more info: [How can I diagnose missing dependencies (or other loader failures) in dnx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29007962/how-can-i-diagnose-missing-dependencies-or-other-loader-failures-in-dnx), and [Diagnosing dependency issues with ASP.NET 5](http://davidfowl.com/diagnosing-dependency-issues-with-asp-net-5/)